# fetch JSON data like [{"key":"[{'key': 'value ','key': 'value '}]"}] in AngularJS and show in a table

Tags: angularjs

Please help me guys.I want that solution .I tried that one don't know where it is wrong maybe because of **single quote**.

```
<tbody style="text-align: center;" >
    <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in metrics.summary_feature_param[0] track by $index ">
```

and data is like

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "sub_system_name": "energy_management",
    "training_dataset_size": 764544,
    "training_time": 2.222,
    "last_training_time": 1537368562000,
    "score_parameters": "[{'accuracy': '91.75 %.', 'mean_absolute_error': '2.56 degrees.'}]",

  }
]
```

Comment: `track by $index` is redundant

Comment: i did but no value is comming

Comment: Show us whole code and html.

Comment: It is not working because `metrics.summary_feature_param` is a **string**, but you treat it as object(`key,value in metrics.summary_feature_param`). You should `JSON.parse` it, but seems it is not valid a JSON.

Comment: Sir,because of single quotes and inner data square bracket directly i can't convert.Any other way is there to fetch it directly.